# Moving down entire wordpress installment one folder

Tags: wordpress, file-move

I've been developing a wordpress website on the same place where it's supposed to go live, just in a /beta folder to keep it from regular visitors. Now it's done, I need to put it live, by moving the entire wordpress installment I have in the /beta folder, down into the root of the domain.

The problems I encountered when I first tried this were that everything automatically links back to the /beta folder, for example my stylesheets link to the right location but the /beta/ folder is included in the link, and I can't seem to find out where to change this. I've tried the Yoast wordpress move tutorial but that seems to be made for entirely different domains, and this is inside the same domain.

So, how would I change the automatic linking? It's not all in the .htaccess file, that's just for in-site permalinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress Codex has a canonical document for this, [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Whether you're moving from domain to domain, or inside the same domain, doesn't matter. The process is always the same.